# Java List<String> to Short

Tags: java, string, list, loops, short

I have this list of string:

```
private final List<String> categoryList = Arrays.asList("27", "28, 96", "10", "15", "7", "98");
```

From the above list,  "28, 96" is considered as one item (Not a typo). Converting each of them to short have no problems except for that one item:

```
for ( int m = 1; m < categoryList.size(); m++) {
    short layerValue = Short.parseShort(categoryList.get(m));
}
```

I'm getting this error converting the "28, 96":

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "28, 96"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:117)
    at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:143)
```

But if I add it directly:

```
//pmTPSelectList[0].layerRateList = new short[] {layerValue};
pmTPSelectList[0].layerRateList = new short[] {28, 96};
```

It works properly. So, I'm confused as to why it is and if there's a way to convert it as I need to loop a couple of values to replace the layervalue (Short)??? ty

Comment: having new Short[] {28, 96} will be an array and compiler can understand by removing "," internally. But with parseShort("28, 96") will throw error as compiler cannot convert "," to short or compiler will take the whole parameter "28, 98" as a single string to convert to short. hence error is thrown. So have a check for presence of "," and remove the same before parseShort();

Comment: What do you expect from parse 28,96 into short? Short is an integer type, it means that it has no decimals. If you want to have two values, then split (check the answers) so you will have two numbers (28 and 96).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split that part up aswell in a second for loop

```
for (String shortstr : categoryList) {
    String[] splitstr = shortstr.split(',');
    for (String innershort: splitstr) {
        short layerValue = Short.parseShort(innershort.trim());
        // add it to a list
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use short as a variable name.

Comment: You got trim() for short data type?? trim should be within parseShort parameter as Short.parseShort(innershort.trim())

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) both  Jayaprasad and Puce were right

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to convert the "28, 96" to a short, it is absolutly normal to get a `NumberFormatException` since a comma is not allowed in `shorts`. In your example you dont have two numbers, but instead you have the String "28, 96".

The comma in line `pmTPSelectList[0].layerRateList = new short[] {28, 96};` is interpred as seperator between the two numbers. Is is not a part of it (what it is in the first case).

Answer (score 0):

If you parse: `"10", "15"` you will get `new short[] {10, 15};`
If you parse: `"28, 96"` you will get error.

Do you see difference? You say that you do not have typo, if so then you intention is wrong.